# Why is $\int_0^{2\pi}{\sin x\over x}$ bigger than 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Why is $\int_0^{2\pi}{\sin x\over x}$ bigger than 0? I really try to understand the concept. If I were asked if $\int_0^{\pi}{\sin x\over x}$ bigger than 0, I would know it is $\int_0^{\pi}{\sin x\over x}$ because in that domain, $\sin x\over x$ is positive. But what about $[0,2\pi]$? Am I actually looking at the total area of $\sin x\over x$ between $0$ and $2\pi$? Right here it is $\int_0^{\pi}{\sin x\over x}+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\sin x\over x}$ while the aforementioned area is $\int_0^{\pi}{\sin x\over x}+|\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\sin x\over x}|=\int_0^{\pi}{\sin x\over x}-\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\sin x\over x}$. How do I solve this issue, then?

Comment: Intuitively, you can see that when $\sin x$ is negative, $x$ is bigger, hence $\frac 1x$ is smaller, leading to a term which contributes less. Of course you have to prove it correctly, but this is not difficult.

Comment: You are right. I almost overlooked it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\sin x$ is is equal in magnitude over the two ranges, but $1/x$ is smaller over $[\pi,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 8):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx-\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x+\pi}dx\\
&=\pi\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x(x+\pi)}dx>0\\
\end{align}